# Execute custom hooks when a state changes created by another custom hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating two hooks. One loads a page content. The other loads a script when a page content is loaded. I don't want to put them into one hooks. How could you do that? Thanks,

```
const useLoadScript = () => {
  useEffect(
    if (page !== undefined) {
      loadScript()
    }    
  , [page])  // how to pass page state to this hooks?
}

const HomePage = () => {
  const [page, loading] = usePage(pageId)  
  useLoadScript()  // how can this be called when page changes?
  return <Page page={page}>
}
```

Comment: how about passing `page` as an argument to `useLoadScript`  as `useLoadScript(page)` and the rest all same

Comment: I've just confirmed it works nicely. Now I'm questioning myself why I thought it would be impossible. Thanks!

Comment: may be because we can't call the hooks conditionally 